# remember user action addon sdk

Tags: redirect, button, firefox-addon, browser-cache

i want to redirect user when connecting to precise url, im  using notificationsbox with 2 button , each one redirect the user to an url1 , i want to  memorize his choice to remember the redirected url1 each time he visit the some url.
  `var nb = mainWindow.gBrowser.getNotificationBox();`
`var n = nb.getNotificationWithValue('popup-blocked');`
 `if(n) {`
  `n.label = message;`
   `} else {`
    `var buttons = [{`
     `label: 'execute this time',`
      `accessKey: 'A',`
       `popup: null,`
        `callback:  function() {`
         `dom = "url1";`
          `}`
           `},{`
            `label: 'execute always',`
             `accessKey: 'B',`
              `popup: null,`
               `callback: function() {`
                `tabs.open("url2");`
                 `dom = "url2";`
                  `}`
                   `}];`
how i can remember his choice 
  1st : just this time 
  2nd: always

Comment: Create a preference and update that value when the user makes a choice. On show of box read the pref value and update it. Option 2: Thre's an attribute called persist. Look into that. Option 3: Addon-SDK has this thing called [simple-storage module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/simple-storage)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is so heavily bugged.

Here is the copy paste code to scratchpad with environment = browser. So other people can help too. And hopefully this can show you how to use it if you didn't know how.

```
var mainWindow = window;
var nb = mainWindow.gBrowser.getNotificationBox(mainWindow.gBrowser.selectedTab.linkedBrowser);
console.log('nb',nb);
var n = nb.getNotificationWithValue('popup-blocked');
if (n) {
    n.label = 'myyy message';
} else {
    var buttons = [{
        label: 'execute this time',
        accessKey: 'A',
        popup: null,
        callback: function () {
            dom = "url1";
        }
    }, {
        label: 'execute always',
        accessKey: 'B',
        popup: null,
        callback: function () {
            mainWindow.gBrowser.loadOneTab('about:blank');
            dom = "url2";
        }
    }];

    var priority = nb.PRIORITY_WARNING_MEDIUM;
    nb.appendNotification('asdfasdf', 'popup-blocked',
                         'chrome://browser/skin/Info.png',
                          priority, buttons);
}

console.log('n',n);
```